# factory with using enum

Tags: java, enums

Let's assume we have factory with a private map

```
clas Factory {
    EnumMap<Color, SomeInterface> map;
    Enum Color {
        FOO,
        BAR
    }
}
```

and would like to expose possibility to get object which implements SomeInterface

```
SomeInterface get(Color color)
```

or implement separeted method per color

```
SomeInterface getFoo();
SomeInterface getBar();
```

**Should it be implemented as single get or multiplie?**

Comment: Depends on your preference, but I find it easier and prettier to use single get. All your interfaces are child of the same interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Enums can implement interfaces. This way you do not need the Factory. This way you do not need the Map. This way you do not need the getter-methods.

Neither foo nor bar is a color, also to enumerate colors some people might mention that there are some more colors than two colors only. SomeInterface is not a talking name for a interface. The construction-method of a Factory-class should not be named *get*, it should be named create or construct.

To use the first method or the second? Since you can really choose between them it looks like `get(Color)` can handle all the work `getFoo` and `getBar` does by themselfes. That indicates that `getFoo` and `getBar` will look pretty similar. Assuming we have 30 more colors beside foo and bar, we will have 30 more getter for all the 30 more colors. Since `getFoo` and `getBar` will look similar all the other 30 more getters will look similar too. This will lead the developer to one question: Should I repeat myself? There is a principle to do not repeat yourself (DRY). Respecting this Dont-Repeat-Yourself(DRY) guides us to prefer the first method, not the second method.